# Change javafx ColorPicker value to fill color of Shape object

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a simple javafx application for a school assignment.  It is a drawing application with a series of different shapes that you can draw.  It also has an edit mode that can change the fill and stroke colors of the currently selected object.  When you select an object in Edit mode the ColorPicker that I use for the fill color is supposed to change to reflect the fill color of the selected object. 
The name of the colorpicker for the fill color is `fillColorPickerButton` and the shape is called `currShape`.

I have tried doing 
`fillColorPickerButton.valueProperty().bind(shape.fillProperty());`
and 
`fillColorPickerButton.setValue(currShape.getFill())`
but with both of them I am told that I cannot convert the Paint class given by the to the Color class required by the ColorPicker.

I am still fairly new to javafx and am not sure how to handle this.  Is there some way to convert paint to Color?  Or am I going about this all wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: If you bind the value of the color picker, you will get exceptions when the user chooses something (because you cannot set a bound value, and the color picker will set its value on selection). You probably just want to call `setValue(...)`. As long as you know you are only setting the fill to `Color` objects, you can just downcast `currShape.getFill()` to a `Color`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but my current problem is that I am getting a Paint object from the Shape class and I need a Color object to set the value of the ColorPicker.

Comment: As I said, all you need to do is downcast it.

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't read more carefully.  Thanks for your help.